# iPhone Game Development

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Today I just need some tips for my first iPhone Game.

In this game you need to protect something from enemies. But I don't know how to create this enemies randomly, and how I can save the data to each enemy (there can be many on the screen at once!)..?

I hope someone can give good tips or good links to tutorials..?

Greetings,
mavrick3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mavrick i think this link might help you

http://www.71squared.com/iphone-tutorials/

Edit:
if you the source code of iPhone Game Development than follow this link

http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4587

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could check : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Good luck

Comment: I just wrote on this site. Thank you, but there aren't many users, so my question will be still open for any tips from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Ray Wenderlich has some great tutorials on his blog about iPhone game development as well as many other iPhone related topics.

This [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) should get you started.

Also if you don't mind purchasing books, I highly recommend these two books.

[Beginning iPhone Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225998)

[Learn iPhone and iPad cocos2d Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233036)